# Can I have common CD for 64 bit Ubuntu and 32 bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

Why does not Ubuntu have a common CD to install Ubuntu, choosing at time of installation whether to install 32 bit or 64 bit Ubuntu, Like Windows disks. Is there any tweak that would allow installation of 32 bit Ubuntu and 64 bit Ubuntu from same CD?

Comment: Do you need to be able to install both from the same *CD*, or would it be okay for it to be a *DVD*? (DVDs are bigger and one could probably be made containing all the essential 64-bit and 32-bit packages for a desktop system. Considering that the graphical Ubiquity installer works by copying most of the live system to the hard disk, it would probably be easiest to create a dual-boot live DVD where one chooses at boot time which live environment to enter, each with its own installer. I'm not sure how to do this properly, which is why I haven't made an answer.)

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks, I already know that you have to create multiboot DVD from two different images of ubuntu each for 32 bit and 64 bit, to do this you can use XBOOT – Multiboot ISO USB Creator (Windows) or YUMI – Multiboot USB Creator or MultiSystem – Create a MultiBoot USB from Linux or SARDU – Multiboot USB Creator (Windows) and there are at least few others.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge, but maybe someone else can tell you if one exists. It is usually expected that the user will know the target platform and download the appropriate DVD. Having 2 DVDs has never been a cause of concern for me.

I stand corrected. Had a look around after reading the comments above and you can use multicd on Linux.http://multicd.tuxfamily.org looks good, I'm going to try it out myself.